# How to get the row(s) with the max value over multiple ordered columns in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following rather complicated data structure:

```
|id|company|technique_id|value_1|value_2|value_3|
|10|   A   |     1      |  98   |   95  |  50   |
|10|   A   |     2      |  96   |   95  |   0   |
|10|   B   |     1      |  96   |   20  |   0   |
|10|   B   |     2      |  99   |   96  |  95   |
|10|   B   |     3      |  95   |   94  |  10   |
|11|   A   |     1      |  96   |   96  |   0   |
|11|   C   |     1      |  99   |   97  |   0   |
...
```

What I want to achieve is to get the company that

1. stores the highest value
2. that is > 95
3. per technique
4. but consider the order of the three `value_x` columns.

So for the above table for the id `10` I would like to get

```
|id|technique_1|technique_2|technique_3|
|10|    A,B    |     B     |    NULL   |
```

**Explaination:**

For technique_id `1` both company `A` and company `B`'s values in `value_2`and `value_3` are `<95`, which is why these columns shouldn't be considered. ANd both their values in `value_1` are greater `>95` they should be both stated in the result table for that id and technique_id.

For technique_id `2` both companies' values in `value_3` are under the threshold again. However, in `value_2` only company B is higher than 95, which is why it is the only company stated in the result table.

Finally, for technique_id `3` only company `B` offers this technique. However, all `value_x` columns are `<95`, which is why no company should be listed for this technique.

I was thinking something with `CASE...WHEN...THEN` with a mix of `max()` functions might be the right way to go, but I somehow cannot get my head around the correct way of getting this result table.

Comment: postgres (as stated in the headline)

Comment: I'm not following the logic.  `value_1` for B/1 is 94, so I don't see why it is in the "1' column.

Comment: Your explanation and data disagree. Please present a consistent question. And always disclose your version of Postgres.

Comment: Company C technique 1 has values 1 and 2 >95 so it should be returned in the query.

Comment: @bobflux Yeah, I was concentrating on id `10` for the result table

Comment: What does "consider the order of the three value_x columns" means? Does it mean that values in these columns are always ordered as they are in the example, with highest value in column 1?

Comment: Ordered in importance. So the highest importance is column `value_3`. If a company `A` would be the only one that has >95 in `value_3` then it doesn't matter what other companies have in the other two `value_x` columns. In the result only `A` would be present

Answer (score 0):

I think you are describing this logic

```
select id,
       array_agg(company) filter (where technique = 1),
       array_agg(company) filter (where technique = 2),
       array_agg(company) filter (where technique = 3)
from t
where value_1 > 95 or value_2 > 95 or value_3 > 95
group by id;
```

This seems consistent with your description but doesn't produce exactly the results you specify.

I much prefer arrays to strings, but you can use `string_agg()` if you prefer.

Comment: Thx for the answer. And yes indeed, the value in the table I discribed above was not consistent with the explanation. I changed it accordingly. However, your query would output `A,B` for technique_id `2` because in `value_1` company A has >95 as well. But in this case `value_2` has a higher importance and here only company B is over 95. Which is why only `B` should be stated in the result table (this is what I meant with "ordered columns")

Answer (score 0):

> the highest importance is column value_3. If a company A would be the only one that has >95 in value_3 then it doesn't matter what other companies have in the other two value_x columns. In the result only A would be present

So the existence of a row with value_3>95 influences whether rows where value_2>95 will be included in the result. This can't be done with a simple query using CASE statements because these only refer to the current row.

So I went with an approach like: select all the rows where value_3>=95, then add rows where value_2=95 with technique_id not found in the previous step, etc.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  company TEXT NOT NULL,
  technique_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  value_1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
  value_2 INTEGER NOT NULL,
  value_3 INTEGER NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO foo VALUES 
(10, 'A', 1, 98, 95, 50 ),
(10, 'A', 2, 96, 95,  0 ),
(10, 'B', 1, 96, 20,  0 ),
(10, 'B', 2, 99, 96, 95 ),
(10, 'B', 3, 95, 94, 10 ),
(11, 'A', 1, 96, 96,  0 ),
(11, 'C', 1, 99, 97,  0 );

WITH
 a AS ( SELECT DISTINCT f.technique_id, f.company FROM foo f WHERE value_3 >= 95 ),
 b AS ( SELECT DISTINCT f.technique_id, f.company FROM foo f LEFT JOIN a USING (technique_id) WHERE f.value_2 >= 95 AND a.technique_id IS NULL ),
 c AS ( SELECT DISTINCT f.technique_id, f.company FROM foo f LEFT JOIN b USING (technique_id) WHERE f.value_1 >= 95 AND b.technique_id IS NULL )
 SELECT technique_id, array_agg(DISTINCT company) FROM (SELECT * FROM a UNION ALL SELECT * FROM b UNION ALL SELECT * FROM c) d GROUP BY technique_id;
```

This gives different results than in the question, because I used ">=", feel free to decide if you want ">" instead.